# Should we choose our own mods?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I haven't been a part of SE for long enough to know much about how moderators are chosen, but would it help us if we picked a few key heavy users, and made them moderators? Or is it too early for that? I'm thinking that we should have a few mods for this site only, until the site is ready to leave beta, at which time we should give the community another chance. Anyone have any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: Nominations have begun, see http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216/moderator-nominations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this article on [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) the timelines may slip a bit depending on Robert and Rebecca's workload.

Comment: The article says we're meant to start our nomination thread immediately, so I've done that: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216/moderator-nominations (I've asked @Zypher in chat to make it CW).

Comment: Tony, no need to make meta questions CW you don't gain or lose rep on child metas - the only exception is meta.so .. which is ... different in more way than one

Answer (score 4):

A couple of weeks into the beta SOIS (the people that run the site) will choose moderators *pro tempore* (temporary moderators) based on people they feel they can trust while the site develops in the beta. Once the site launches, the community *will* choose their own moderators through an election process.

Example from Programmers.SE:

- [Moderator Pro Tem Announcement](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311/moderator-pro-tem-announcement)
- [2011 Community Moderator Election](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1019/2011-community-moderator-election)

I know Programmers.SE intimately, but the process is the same for all Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: How are the moderators chosen? Are they from the active users, or the more general SE moderators?

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto The post Zypher linked to describes the moderators *pro tempore* selection process: generally active people who demonstrate a knowledge of what the site is about, an ability to be level-headed, and the qualities described in [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

Comment: LOL, looks like I'm asking the question about the right time. They say 7 days into the public beta, so that'd be about 2 more days... Hmmm.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto that's an estimate that can slip. In the case of Programmers.SE, it took 16 days.

Comment: Quite frankly, I think that this site needs liasons quicker than normal, and I think there's probably enough information to pick out who these people might be. Still, I can understand that if it's sufficiently busy, it might take a little while longer...